# Polymer 1.0 can't access elements within nested <template> element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I am using Polymer 1.0 and I am building a small accordion example. I have data binding to the accordion text fine, I just want to change the icon of the accordion when I click it.

Below is my code

```
<dom-module id="ab-accordion">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax              
      auto
      handle-as="json"
      on-response="handleResponse"
      debounce-duration="300"
      id="ajaxreq"></iron-ajax>

    <template is="dom-repeat" id="accordion" items="{{items}}" as="item">
      <div class="accordion"  on-click="toggleParentAcc">
        <div id="accordion_header" class="accordion__header is-collapsed">
          <i class="icon icon--chevron-down"></i>
          <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div id="standard_accordion_body" class="accordion__body can-collapse">
          <div class="accordion__content">
            <content id="content"></content>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>   
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "ab-accordion",
      //Properties for the Element
      properties: {
        accordian: Object,
        childaccordions: Object,
        // Param passed in from the element - Set if the accordion is open by default.
        open: String,
        data: String,
        reqUrl: {
          type: String,
          value: "https://example.com/service.aspx"
        },
      },
      ready: function () {
        this.items = [];
      },
      attached: function () {
        // Run once the element is attached to the DOM.
      },
      toggleParentAcc: function (event) { // Toggle the classes of the accordions
        //This is where I want to toggle the  class
        this.$.accordion_header.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
        if (typeof event !== 'undefined') {
          event.stopPropagation(); // Stop the click from going up to the parent.
        }
      },
      handleResponse: function (e) {
        this.items = e.detail.response.sports;
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Basically inside the `toggleParentAcc` function I want to toggle the class of the div with ID `accordion_header`. But I just get undefined or null.

I have tried the following two lines:

```
this.$.accordion_header // #1
this.$$('#accordion_header') // #2
```

How I access that element inside the dom-repeat?

**UPDATE:** I can't even access the elements within the  when inside the attached function.

```
attached: function(){
 this.$.accordion_header // This is null?!
 this.$$('#accordion_header'); // this is also null!
}
```

Comment: FYI - I have removed the URL for the ajax call just to keep my API safe from getting bashed.

Comment: Did you find a solution querying the local DOM?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding

> Note: Nodes created dynamically using data binding (including those in  dom-repeat and dom-if templates) are not added to the this.$ hash. The hash includes only statically created local DOM nodes (that is, the nodes defined in the element’s outermost template).

I think it would be better if you'd use `Polymer.dom(this.root)` instead. Also I'd advice you to not use static IDs in `dom-repeat` as they are meant to be unique. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be encountering **Event Retargeting** which happens when events "bubble" their way up the DOM tree. [Read this documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#retargeting) to learn more.

When I encountered this, I solved it by using something like:

```
var bar = Polymer.dom(event).path[2].getAttribute('data-foo');
```

inside my `Polymer()` function.

To figure it out in your case, you should go to the console and search the DOM tree / event log to locate your target. If you have trouble locating the correct area of the console, post a comment and I might be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I can't even access the elements in the attached function. I want to pass in a param "Open" and if it's true I wan to open the accordion by default. This is where I need to target the div with the id "accordion_header" and change it's class. Please see updated code above and take a look at my attached function.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out a way of doing this without having to select elements in the nested template.

```
<template id="accord_template" is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="item">
        <ab-accordion-row id="[[item.id]]" name="[[item.name]]" open="[[item.open]]">
        </ab-accordion-row>
    </template>
```

ab-accordion is another element, I just feed it the data and I can then change the classes based on the params.

```
    <div id="accordion" class="accordion" on-click="toggleAccordion">
        <div  class$="{{getClassAccordionHeader(open)}}">
            <i class="icon icon--chevron-down"></i>
            <span>{{name}}</span>
        </div>
        <div id="standard_accordion_body" class$="{{getClassAccordionChild(open)}}">
            <div class="accordion__content">
                <content></content>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
toggleParentAcc: function (event) { // Toggle the classes of the accordions
    //This is where I want to toggle the  class
    var header = event.target.parentElement;
    Polymer.dom(header).classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
    // rest of your code
  }
```